# Oracle 12c, creating new instance and database, LSNRCTL does not see service

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, tnsnames

I'am trying to setup a new database on oracle 12c. I did this many times and in my opinion, there's nothing I did wrong.
Important thing - I have also 11g installation in same folder (product) so to run f.e. sqlplus or oradim for security I run from /BIN directory with ".exe" on the end.

First:

```
set ORACLE_SID=testdb
set LOCAL=testdb
new service - oradim.exe -new -sid %ORACLE_SID% -intpwd system -startmode M
```

in services.msc there's everything ok - service showed up and run.
Next: initdb.ora & tnsnames.ora-

```
testdb =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = testdb) //here i also try (SID = testdb)
    )
  )
```

init:

```
control_files = (C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\dbs\control01.ora, 
                 C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\dbs\control02.ora, 
                 C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\dbs\control03.ora) 
undo_management = auto 
db_name         = ora10 
db_block_size       = 8192
```

then

from cmd line with Admin rights i tried

```
sqlplus "/as sysdba"
sqlplus sys/system@testdb
sqlplus sys/system    
sqlplus /nolog -> connect sys/system as sysdba  --since local and ORACLE_SID are set
```

and I always get an "unkown service or sid" error.
So I checked lsnrctl.exe status and my testdb isn't there.
Why? :|

Comment: Are you sure about right ORACLE_HOME enviroment variable? Try command "tnsping testdb" an you'll see at least which .ora file used

Comment: Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = testdb
)))
OK (20 msec)

I have already tried this, forgot to mention. :)

Comment: if c:\> lsnrctl status doesn't list your db, you probably just need to edit your listener.ora in %oracle_home%\network\admin to add the entry for your testdb... Then reload the listener via: c:\> lsnrctl reload

Answer (score 0):

try to restart the listener and register your sid dynamically with listener.

alter system set **local_listener**=testdb